# If a Dynamics 365 plugin has no steps does it not do anything?

Tags: plugins, dynamics-crm, crm, microsoft-dynamics

If I find a plugin in the solution but it has not steps, may I delete it since it isn't doing anything? I believe a plugin without steps is impossible to trigger.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, without any steps registered it is safe to say that the plugin is doing nothing.
However, to be safe you might want to put it into an unmanaged solution and export that solution before you delete it.

Comment: We have the plugin sitting in TFS, I know it's an exact copy because I registered the DLL. Since I have it in TFS would you say it would be safe to perhaps unregister it and exclude that cs file from the TFS project?

Comment: Cool, as long as you have a recovery option, then you can delete it from the system and exclude it from the TFS project.